# Prevent webpack from removing my exported function

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, webpack, blazor

Im trying to create a `Razor Class Library` which is exposing 1 js function. My problem is that webpack removes my exported function in final bundle file.

`index.js`

```
import * as myLib from "someLib"

export function connect(params) {
    // function logic omitted for clarity
}
```

And this is how I want to consume the js code

```
using MyComponent.Common;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace MyComponent.Services
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> _myWrapper;

        public MyService(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            _myWrapper = new Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>>(() =>
                jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./_content/MyComponent/index.bundle.js")
                    .AsTask());
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task Connect(params)
        {
            if (_myWrapper is null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrapper is not initialized");
            }

            IJSObjectReference module = await _myWrapper.Value;

            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("connect", params);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I get is (as expected because there is no connect function exposed in index.bundle.js)

```
Could not find 'connect' ('connect' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'connect' ('connect' was undefined).
    at https://localhost:7134/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:328
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at a.findFunction (https://localhost:7134/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:296)
    at _ (https://localhost:7134/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:2437)
    at https://localhost:7134/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3325
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:7134/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3306)
    at Object.St [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (https://localhost:7134/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:59849)
    at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (https://localhost:7134/_framework/dotnet.6.0.2-mauipre.1.22102.15.kf8l5pkaed.js:1:194973)
    at wasm://wasm/00970ba6:wasm-function[219]:0x1a129
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a way to fix this. At the end of `index.js` I inserted the following line

```
window.connect = connect;
```

This makes webpack not to delete the connect function, however it's still not usable via `IJSObjectReference` because it expects the function to be exported like `export function connect` so I inserted another line at the end of final `index.bundle.js`

```
export function connect(params) { window.connect(params); }
```

I also had to disable auto webpack builds on my csproj file since my modifications would be lost after every build and that's it, I was able to use my function just fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update 2024

For anyone looking for a solution in Webpack:

Set the property:
`output.library.type` to `commonjs2` or `commonjs-module` [Read more](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytype). It also requires `output.library.name` to be set.

```json
{
...
"output": {
  "library": {
    "type": "commonjs2", // or: "commonjs-module"
    "name": "yourLibraryName"
  }
}
...
}
```

This would expose the methods with `module.exports.<methodName> = <method>` at the end of the generated file